# show admob ads at the bottom of the RelativeLayout using java no XML

Tags: android, android-layout, admob, android-relativelayout, android-view

I have designed a game with **no xml layouts**.I have used my **own view** extending the **SurfaceView** class .This is the code i am using.

```
RelativeLayout rl = new RelativeLayout(this);
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lay = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);


    lay.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM);

    _ad=new AdView(this,AdSize.BANNER,"################");

    rl.addView(myView);
    rl.addView(_ad);

    _ad.loadAd(new AdRequest());
    setContentView(rl);
```

myView is the instance of class extending SurfaceView 
 and
 _ad is the AdView instance.

**I want to show the the ads at the bottom of the screen.But they are getting displayed only at the top.**

Please suggest me what to do.I will be very grateful.

Comment: The problem was ,I forgot to attach the **lay** variable to the AdView. i.e **rl.addView(_ad,lay)** . This is it.I have not deleted this post because I have seen many developer looking for this problem's solution but are not able to find it.This is for them.Thank You

Comment: Please add your answer in the answer box so people know where to look to find the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only mistake I was doing was not associating my LayoutParams **lay** variable with the **_ad** AdView instance.So here is the code after modification.

```
RelativeLayout rl = new RelativeLayout(this);
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lay = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);


lay.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM);

_ad=new AdView(this,AdSize.BANNER,"################");

rl.addView(myView);
rl.addView(_ad,lay); //line which was changed.Everything else was correct

_ad.loadAd(new AdRequest());
setContentView(rl);
```

Thank You StackOverflow.